# Do Brazilians need a work permit to work in the UK for under 6 months?

Tags: visa, working-visas, brazilian-citizens

I am considering employing Brazilians to work as IT contractors in the UK will they need to have Tier 2 work permit? What else will they need legally?

Comment: Would you consider hiring locally? There is plenty of UK talent available for IT work.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you will need a license as an employer who can issue Certificates of Sponsorship. You will be allotted a certain number depending on your qualifications. Once these are issued to the future employee, they can then apply for a Tier 2 visa. There are many requirements such as minimum pay requirement, RMLT as well as the demonstrated skills to do the job.